# "Integer Float" Exact Conversion to Float

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point

I am working with a library that uses `int` for representing money amounts. For example, the following is what this looks like:

`599` --> $5.99
`500` --> $5.00
`5` --> $0.05
`0` --> $0.00
`-599` --> $-5.99

I wrote the following function which does an *exact* float conversion without causing floating point errors, but what I am wondering is if I am approaching this the wrong way or if there is a much *cleaner* solution.

```py
def money_int_to_float(value: int) -> float:
    neg: str = '-' if value < 0 else ''
    value = abs(value)

    cents: int = value % 100
    remaining: int = value - cents
    dollars: int = int(str(remaining).removesuffix('00'))
    return float(f'{neg}{dollars}.{str(cents).zfill(2)}')
```

My reasoning for wanting an *exact* float conversion is that when dealing with money you can never be too careful with floats.

Comment: If you want exactness, why are you using floats, which are by their nature inexact?  There's a reason this library is using integer cents instead of floating point dollars in the first place; IMO you'd be better off doing the same.  :)  If you do want an "exact" non-integer decimal, look into the `Decimal` class.

Comment: @Samwise You are correct, but for the sake of the question, let's say I need it in float format and don't intend to use the float for further calculations.

Comment: There might be very few values, were your conversion is "more exact" than just doing `value / 100` (e.g., if `value` does not fit into a `float`). Otherwise, you win nothing. The problem with using floats for currency is that certain values are not representable, not that the conversion is inexact.

Comment: That's a contradiction -- if you're not going to use it in calculations, then it doesn't need to be a float.  It sounds like maybe you actually want to just convert it to a string (which you can do without any actual numeric operations).  If you actually want a float, the best solution is to dimply do `value / 100`, but be aware that (like chtz said) you can't necessarily represent an arbitrary decimal (even one that looks relatively "round" as a decimal) as a floating point binary number with exactly the same value.  The string manipulation stuff you're doing doesn't change that.

Comment: What do you mean by "*exact* float conversion"? In general it's impossible for the result to be exact in all cases; the best you can do is "correctly-rounded" - i.e., aim for the _closest_ representable `float` to the actual value you need. And in current CPython, `value / 100` already does exactly that - it gives you the closest possible `float` to the actual mathematical quotient (rounding ties to even, as usual).

Comment: Using an `int` with a scaling is called fixed-point format. Converting that fixed-point number to a decimal numeral in a string and then converting that numeral to a floating-point number is no better than converting the fixed-point number directly to floating-point. Simply returning `value/100` will give you the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod) sounds like something you should know about:

```
def money_int_to_str(value: int) -> str:
    sign = '-' if value < 0 else ''
    dollars, cents = divmod(abs(value), 100)
    return f'${sign}{dollars}.{cents:02}'
```

the reason for staying away from floats would be that, e.g., `money_int_to_float(123456789123456789)` won't give you 89 cents from any implementation – there isn't enough precision in a float to store it.

Comment: I have never found a use for `divmod` until today. This is an excellent usage of it, thank you for this answer!

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to @Samwise's comment, I have found a clean solution to this question. Using the [Decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) class we can rewrite the function as follows:

```py
from decimal import Decimal

def money_int_to_float(value: int) -> float:
    return float(Decimal(value).quantize(Decimal('0.00')).shift(-2))
```

Comment: This will give you exactly the same result that `value / 100` would have given you. The only difference is that it'll be slower, and that the code is harder to read and understand. If you really do need a `float` here, why not simply use `value / 100`?

Comment: Even if your `Decimal` value is exact, the `float` it converts to won't be.